# VB.Net XSLT transformation for converting single xml file to multiple html file

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I have designed a xslt2.0 file which will transform a single xml file to multiple html files. I have succeeded in transformation using xslt tools, but i am looking for vb.net code which will perform the above transformation. could any help me in this regard, thanks in advance.

-Hari

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not provide an XSLT 2.0 processor in the .NET framework so you will need to use third party solutions like the .NET version of Saxon 9.5 or like XmlPrime. See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!dotnet/dotnetapi for the API of Saxon on .NET and see http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/doc/2.9/using-xslt.htm for the API of XmlPrime.